# String to ISO Date

Tags: mongodb

I've looked this up a few times and no answer has worked so far. I want to turn a string date into an ISODate - I don't want it converted to or from UTC, I just want to make the date value which is stored as string to be **stored** as a date.

I don't want UTC because I want to query against and calculate based upon a time of day (example: 12pm) anywhere in the world and I'm summing by hour, day, week and month and comparing data across many countries based upon local time.

Currently I have a date as a string which I want to add to a new document with a new name:

**"transaction_date": "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.sale_date"**

The date value as string below is shown as:

"sale_date" : "2018-03-13 20:05:46"

I want it to be: "transaction_date" : ISODate("2018-03-13 20:05:46")

The date and time must read 2018-03-13 20:05:46 not converted to UTC.

Thanks, Matt

Origin Data JSON

```
{ 
"object_category" : "application", 
"object_type" : "register-sales-24-months", 
"object_origin" : "vend", 
"tenant_uuid" : "00000000-0000-0009-9999-999999999999", 
"party_uuid" : "8d519765-05d2-469f-ad35-d7a22fa9df2f", 
"subscription_uuid" : "0", 
"connection_uuid" : "6ed9bd79-d9c5-4296-a821-7e15b1c69e6c", 
"status" : "", 
"object_created" : ISODate("2018-03-15T21:40:57.158+0000"), 
"object_raw_origin_data" : {
    "pagination" : {
        "results" : NumberInt(75964), 
        "page" : NumberInt(1), 
        "page_size" : NumberInt(200), 
        "pages" : NumberInt(380)
    }, 
    "register_sales" : {
        "id" : "776a66f2-993c-b372-11e8-26f9d3c1bdde", 
        "source" : "USER", 
        "source_id" : "", 
        "register_id" : "02dcd191-ae55-11e6-edd8-ec8dce1d9e1c", 
        "market_id" : "3", 
        "customer_id" : "02d59481-b67d-11e5-f667-b08185e8f6d5", 
        "customer_name" : "", 
        "customer" : {
            "id" : "02d59481-b67d-11e5-f667-b08185e8f6d5", 
            "name" : "", 
            "customer_code" : "WALKIN", 
            "customer_group_id" : "02d59481-b67d-11e5-f667-b08185e893f8", 
            "customer_group_name" : "All Customers", 
            "updated_at" : "2016-01-01 12:16:44", 
            "deleted_at" : "", 
            "balance" : "0", 
            "year_to_date" : "0", 
            "date_of_birth" : "", 
            "sex" : "", 
            "custom_field_1" : "", 
            "custom_field_2" : "", 
            "custom_field_3" : "", 
            "custom_field_4" : "", 
            "note" : "", 
            "contact" : {
            }
        }, 
        "user_id" : "02d59481-b655-11e5-f667-dca974edc4ea", 
        "user_name" : "Alvaro Velosa", 
        "sale_date" : "2018-03-13 20:05:46", 
        "created_at" : "2018-03-13 20:06:00", 
        "updated_at" : "2018-03-13 20:06:00", 
        "total_price" : 4.5, 
        "total_cost" : 3.34, 
        "total_tax" : NumberInt(0), 
        "tax_name" : "No Tax", 
        "note" : "", 
        "status" : "CLOSED", 
        "short_code" : "wqgsgi", 
        "invoice_number" : "Masonic2108Temple", 
        "accounts_transaction_id" : "", 
        "return_for" : "", 
        "register_sale_products" : [
            {
                "id" : "776a66f2-993c-b372-11e8-26f9e92cb9bc", 
                "product_id" : "02dcd191-ae55-11e7-f130-9d4f4bcd91b1", 
                "register_id" : "02dcd191-ae55-11e6-edd8-ec8dce1d9e1c", 
                "sequence" : "0", 
                "handle" : "LAGERDRAUGHT300", 
                "sku" : "10287", 
                "name" : "LAGER DRAUGHT £3.00", 
                "quantity" : NumberInt(1), 
                "price" : 3.5, 
                "cost" : 2.74, 
                "price_set" : NumberInt(0), 
                "discount" : NumberInt(0), 
                "loyalty_value" : NumberInt(0), 
                "tax" : NumberInt(0), 
                "tax_id" : "02d59481-b67d-11e5-f667-b08185ec2871", 
                "tax_name" : "No Tax", 
                "tax_rate" : NumberInt(0), 
                "tax_total" : NumberInt(0), 
                "price_total" : 3.5, 
                "display_retail_price_tax_inclusive" : "0", 
                "status" : "CONFIRMED", 
                "attributes" : [
                    {
                        "name" : "line_note", 
                        "value" : ""
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "id" : "776a66f2-993c-b372-11e8-26f9e98104e0", 
                "product_id" : "02dcd191-ae55-11e7-f130-9d50e948a0b5", 
                "register_id" : "02dcd191-ae55-11e6-edd8-ec8dce1d9e1c", 
                "sequence" : "0", 
                "handle" : "SOFTDRINK", 
                "sku" : "10292", 
                "name" : "SOFT DRINK", 
                "quantity" : NumberInt(1), 
                "price" : NumberInt(1), 
                "cost" : 0.6, 
                "price_set" : NumberInt(0), 
                "discount" : NumberInt(0), 
                "loyalty_value" : NumberInt(0), 
                "tax" : NumberInt(0), 
                "tax_id" : "02d59481-b67d-11e5-f667-b08185ec2871", 
                "tax_name" : "No Tax", 
                "tax_rate" : NumberInt(0), 
                "tax_total" : NumberInt(0), 
                "price_total" : NumberInt(1), 
                "display_retail_price_tax_inclusive" : "0", 
                "status" : "CONFIRMED", 
                "attributes" : [
                    {
                        "name" : "line_note", 
                        "value" : ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        ], 
        "totals" : {
            "total_tax" : NumberInt(0), 
            "total_price" : 4.5, 
            "total_payment" : 4.5, 
            "total_to_pay" : NumberInt(0)
        }, 
        "register_sale_payments" : [
            {
                "id" : "776a66f2-993c-b372-11e8-26f9eab2cb46", 
                "payment_type_id" : "1", 
                "register_id" : "02dcd191-ae55-11e6-edd8-ec8dce1d9e1c", 
                "retailer_payment_type_id" : "02d59481-b655-11e5-f667-b0a23bc0e7bc", 
                "name" : "Cash", 
                "label" : "Account Customer", 
                "payment_date" : "2018-03-13 20:05:46", 
                "amount" : NumberInt(10)
            }, 
            {
                "id" : "776a66f2-993c-b372-11e8-26f9eab6b21a", 
                "payment_type_id" : "1", 
                "register_id" : "02dcd191-ae55-11e6-edd8-ec8dce1d9e1c", 
                "retailer_payment_type_id" : "02d59481-b655-11e5-f667-b0a23bc0e7bc", 
                "name" : "Cash", 
                "label" : "Account Customer", 
                "payment_date" : "2018-03-13 20:05:46", 
                "amount" : -5.5
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is end goal? update all documents in collection?

Comment: tried changing to:
"transaction_date": new ISODate("$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.sale_date") - failed
"transaction_date": new date("$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.sale_date") and it comes out at midnight in 1970

Comment: thanks @Saleem I'm creating a complete set of documents from documents, doing a transformation. The date in origin is string, I need it to be a date, thanks

Comment: I'm not clear. Do you want to update all documents and convert string to date or just run query and get date instead of string. e.g. aggregation query etc?

Comment: @Saleem sorry yes, I want to update all documents

Comment: date string in `sale_date` is not a valid ISO date string. see 2018-03-13 20:05:46

Comment: @Saleem I discovered that Vend writes sale_date as UTC as a string. My problem is I want to be able to write local time and date in my document. The reason being, I want to query any company anywhere in the world what their sales are like a 1pm on a Monday. I don't want results of 1pm NZT mixed in with UK where the local time is 12am. I hope that explains my problem :(

Comment: my immediate issue is storing the time shown as a date instead of a string, thanks

Comment: yes, if string is not a valid date, how will you convert it to date?

Comment: I cannot understand why YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS isn't a valid date, I'm missing something here. Apologies for the confusion @Saleem

Comment: Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/date-and-time-strings-javascript#iso-date-format

Comment: thanks for your support here, so I can construct from what I have a date from the string right? I have all the ingredients there - I just want it not be a string and not specific to a country's timezone. It doesn't have to be ISODate does it? Isn't there another date format so I don't have to worry about ISO 8601

Comment: MongoDB recognize ISO date formats only. So if it requires, ISODate, we can't force it our way. Think what will happen if you fill Diesel in Patrol car?

Comment: Thanks for your patience @Saleem my problem is that, if I receive an invoice via email and I'm on the other side of the world, the date doesn't show NOW in my time zone it shows the date when the invoice was raised in local time/date.  To not be able to specify a globally applicable date and time and get records where 12pm in New Zealand is 11am in UK and 4am in Los Angelas where you want specifically what happened in EVERY country at 1pm seems very odd. I understand every other reason why UTC is perfect but this one blows my mind

Comment: Matt, I'm not asking you to convert it to UTC. All I'm suggesting to store date in format which conforms to ISO. e.g. `2018-03-13 20:05:46` needs to be `2018-03-13T20:05:46`. pay attention to `T` in date.

Comment: @Matt you can convert to preferred timezone when saving the datetime. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/

Comment: thanks @Krishna for the link, thanks Saleem for putting up with my misunderstanding

Comment: @Krishna I managed to get close to solving this problem, I did a $concat with #substr and got it to a string of "transaction_date" : "2018-03-07T11:36:48". However, when I put in all the script required into a $dateFromString.datesString, it doesn't recognise or understand that at all - see below for more details, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help from @Saleem and @Krishna however, I have tried to create an ISODate using a $concat of $substr from a string and it isn't working.

```
db.Vend_raw_transactions.aggregate(
[{
"$project": {
  "object_origin": "$object_origin",
  "company": "$party_uuid",
  "connection": "$connection_uuid",
  "object_creation_date": "$object_created",
//      "transaction_date": "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.sale_date",


  "transaction_date": {
     "$dateFromString":     {
        "dateString": {
        "$concat":  [ 
            "$substr": [ "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.sale_date", 0, 10 ], 
            "T",
            "$substr": [ "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.sale_date", 11, 9]
                ] 
            }
     }
  },


  "transaction_gross_value": {
    "$add": [
      "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.total_price",
      "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.total_tax"
    ]
  },
  "transaction_net_value": "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.total_price",
  "transaction_tax_value": "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.total_tax",
  "transaction_cost_value": "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.total_cost",
  "object_class": "goods-service-transaction",
  "object_origin_category": "point-of-sale",
  "object_type": "receipt",
  "object_origin_type": "offline",
  "transaction_reference": "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.invoice_number",
  "transaction_status": "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.status",
  "transaction_currency": "GBP",
  "party_name": "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.customer.customer_name",
  "party_identifier": "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.customer.customer_code",
  "staff_identifier": "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.user_id",
  "staff_name": "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.user_name",
  "line_items" : {
      "$map": {
          "input": "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.register_sale_products",
          "as" : "product",
          "in": {"item_name": "$$product.name", 
                "item_system_id": "$$product.id",
                "item_identifier": "$$product.sku",
                "item_category" : "sales-revenue",
                "item_quantity" : "$$product.quantity",
                "item_net_unit_sale_value" : "$$product.price",
                "item_net_unit_discount_value" : "$$product.discount",
                "item_net_unit_member_value" : "$$product.loyalty_value",
                "item_net_unit_cost_value" : "$$product.cost",
                "item_unit_tax_value" : "$$product.tax",
                "item_price_list_reference" : "$$product.price_set",
                "item_total_sale_value" : "$$product.price_total",
                "item_total_tax_value" : "$$product.tax_total"
          }
      }
  }
}
}
//  ,{"$out": "9SP_Source" }
])
```

I cannot work out why this isn't working, it seems like it should - I'm creating a new string based upon an existing string value and adding a T in the middle but it doesn't recognise $DateFromString. Thanks

**Error Message**

{
    "message" : "Unrecognized expression '$dateFromString'",
    "stack" : "MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$dateFromString'" +
              "at queryCallback (C:\Users\mattl\AppData\Local\Programs\nosqlbooster4mongo\resources\app.asar\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:223:25)" +
              "at C:\Users\mattl\AppData\Local\Programs\nosqlbooster4mongo\resources\app.asar\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:541:18" +
              "at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)" +
              "at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)",
    "name" : "MongoError",
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$dateFromString'",
    "code" : 168,
    "codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator"
}

I've managed to make another string using the below script but $dateFromString unrecognised

```
db.Vend_raw_transactions.aggregate(
[{
"$project": {
          "origin_date": "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.sale_date",
  "transaction_date": {
            "$substr": [ "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.sale_date", 0, 10 ]
  },
        "transaction_time": {
            "$substr": [ "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.sale_date", 11, 9 ]
  },
  "new_string_date": {

    "$concat" :[
      {"$substr": [ "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.sale_date", 0, 10 ]}, 
      "T", 
      {"$substr": [ "$object_raw_origin_data.register_sales.sale_date", 11, 9 ]}]

}
}
      }
])
```

Thanks

Comment: ah, I think it might be Mongo 3.6 only - I'm running 3.4 - so what's the alternative to $dateFromString. Surely I'm not the first to have this problem :)

Comment: a whole day researching the most basic thing, turn a date I can read into a date the database recognises - When I type a date it is text, this is driving me round the bloody bend - Can't query by date with dates because its string. Grrrrgghh